# O que quer dizer nível máximo de profundidade?

Tags: mongodb, terminologia

Li recentemente este [artigo](http://www.itexto.net/devkico/?p=1621), o qual está dizendo:

> O nível máximo de profundidade de um documento é 100.

O qual me deixou com a seguinte dúvida:

O que o autor esta querendo dizer com nível de profundidade de um documento?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Documentação](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/).

O MongoDB trabalha com aninhamento de documentos, certo? Você pode ir colocando "sub-documentos" uns dentro dos outros. É como se fossem *tags* XML/HTML, você vai pondo umas dentro das outras. Quando coloca um documento/dado dentro de outro, este é um nível. Quando coloca outro documento dentro deste que acabou de colocar, é outro nível, e assim vai, cada um dentro do outro vai adicionando um nível.

Se pensar em uma caixa dentro da outra, dá para colocar 100 caixas. Claro que se está colocando 2 caixas uma do lado da outra dentro de outra caixa, não está adicionando dois níveis, as duas estão no mesmo nível. Aí é um nível apenas com 2 elementos diferentes, somente quando uma vai dentro da outra que forma um nível. O mesmo poderia ser dito para pastas, diretórios, etc., só que são documentos.